# Python regex to match "John", not "1 John", "2 John" or "3 John"

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I can't see to find a Python 3 regex pattern that will only find "John", but not "1 John", "1Jn", "2 John", "2Jn", "3 John", or "3Jn".

For example in r"1 John, 2 John, 3 John, everywhere a John, John.", I only want it to match the last 2 mentions of John, and NOT the first 3 mentions of John.

I've tried a lot of things, and keep coming back to a Python 3 regex pattern like `r"(?<!\s[123I]\s)(?<!^[123I]\s)Jn|John"`. But this captures all 5 mentions of John, not the just the last two.

Is there a way to get "John", but not "1 John", "1Jn", "2 John", "2Jn", "3 John", or "3Jn"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `^` in the *look behind* pattern which will match all occurrences of `John` as long as it doesn't appear at the beginning of the string due to negative behind; You need to group `Jn` and `John` so that the *look behind* applies to both, since `(?<!^[123I]\s)Jn|John` matches `(?<!^[123I]\s)Jn` or `John`:

```
s = "1 John, 2 John, 3 John, everywhere a John, John."
re.findall(r'(?<![123I] )(?:Jn|John)', s)
# ['John', 'John']
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Actually, your construction works even better if "1Jn." is included in the search string if I amend your solution as follows.

`r"(?<![123I] )(?<![123I])(?:Jn|John)"`